# Custom block theme not appearing in QuickTabs content

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I'm attempting to create a dashboard page that contains 4 tabs that are each a block that will contain a content based on the current user. I went ahead and created the 4 blocks (bl1, bl2, bl3, and bl4), added the blocks to `content` under `block layout` and then created the Quicktabs Instance to display these 4 blocks. So far so good.

However, when I go to customize the tab blocks in my theme, that theme is not getting picked up through quicktabs... My dashboard template looks like so:

**page--dashboard.html.twig**

```
{% block head %}
   {{ drupal_entity('block', 'navigationheader') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div id="main-content" class="container">
    {{ drupal_entity('block', 'quicktabsdashboard') }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
  {{ drupal_entity('block', 'footer') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Then I have 4 template files for each block: `block--bl1.html.twig`, `block--bl2.html.twig`, `block--bl3.html.twig`, and `block--bl4.html.twig`... (FWIW, this project is very customized and these blocks will only be displayed here)

The content from these template files are not being pulled into the quicktabs. If I load the block manually in dashboard like so: `{{ drupal_entity('block', 'bl1') }}` the expected block styling is there..

How do you get quicktabs to show your custom block templates?

*Perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach and shouldn't use quicktabs and instead just write my own tab bar in twig and display the different blocks directly in the dashboard template?*

**Update**

I've done what was suggested in the answer below and got rid of my usage of Twig Tweak and created a new region called `dashboard_tabs` for my quicktabs instance block. I also created a region called `dashboard_content` that contains the blocks I am putting into my quicktabs (so that I can template theme all by name instead of by Id).

Here is what I have now:

**page--dashboard.html.twig**

```
{% block head %}
  <div id="ytp-header">
    {{ page.header_navigation }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="ytp-main-content">
    {{ page.dashboard_tabs }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**region.html.twig**

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'region',
    'region-' ~ region|clean_class,
  ]
%}
{% if content %}
  <section{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {{ content }}
  </section>
{% endif %}
{% if dashboard_tabs %}
  <section{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {{ dashboard_tabs }}
  </section>
{% endif %}
{% if dashboard_content %}
  <section{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {{ dashboard_content }}
  </section>
{% endif %}
```

When I have it like this, this actually creates even more problems for me:

1. The blocks Quicktabs displays still do not use my template for those blocks
   -and-
2. Quicktabs now doesn't change the tab and instead just reloads the page (Ajax broke?)

This seems like it should be fairly simple, but I'm going wrong somewhere obviously. Any tutorials or guides on how to build quicktabs using blocks that have their own template file?

Answer (score 3):

Your appraoch is wrong as you never should render anything with Twig Tweak when you can do it also with `{{ content }}`. If you render more complex things than a simple scalar value with something `{{ node.field_something.value }}` or any of Twig Tweak's functions like `{{ drupal_something() }}` you always have drawbacks like

- block not rendering with correct template
- content being incorrectly cached
- (referenced) entity being rendered in the wrong language

In your case the correct approach would be creating a region for the quicktab blocks, and then render those blocks in the region template file (not page template) with a plain `{{ content }}`.

Everyone of the above problems has a workaround (for Twig Tweak rendered blocks see the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/rendering-blocks-with-twig-tweak)), but I'd defenitly advice not using workarounds when it easily can be done straight forward.

Comment: I went ahead and put the the quicktabs instance block in the `content` region and render the content in page.html.twig via `{{ page.content }}`. A region template exists that renders the quicktabs instance with `{{ content }}`. However, my page with the quicktabs block still doesn't render the tab block with the correct formatting...